# Squares in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the integral binary quadratic form
$$f(x,y) = 2Axy+Bx^2$$
with $A,B \in \mathbb{Z}$ different from $0$. In Cassel's book "Rational quadratic forms" page 237 he claims that for $p \neq 2$ every small enough $a_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is primitively representable by $f$. Further, he says it can be done with $x=1$, namely the quadratic equation
$$By^2 + 2Ay - a_p = 0$$
has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all small enough $a_p$.
The discriminant of the polynomial and it is $\Delta = 4A^2-4Ba_p$ and so for small $a_p$ we have $\left| \Delta \right|_p = \left| 4A^2 \right|_p$. $4A^2$ is of course a square, but I don't think this implies anything about $\Delta$.

Of course, "small enough" means $p$-adically small throughout the question.
Can someone tell me why is this true?

Comment: @DietrichBurde both are non-zero integers and $p \neq 2$. Sorry for the confusion. fixed the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \ne 0$ then you can take $a_p$ small enough so that $|a_p|_p < |2A|^2_p$. Then you apply the (general form of) Hensel's Lemma as follows:

$$f(y) = B y^2 + 2 A y - a_p,$$

Let $a = 0$, then

$$|f(a)|_p = |f(0)|_p = |a_p|_p < |2 A|^2_p = |f'(0)|^2_p = |f'(a)|^2_p.$$

See: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel%27s_lemma_for_p-adic_numbers)

Another way of thinking about it is that any element $t$ in $\mathbf{Q}_p$ sufficiently close to $a^2 \ne 0$ is also a square, as can be proved by applying Hensel's Lemma to $f(x) = x^2 - t$ with the seed $x = a$, and then making sure $f(a) = a^2 - t$ is sufficiently small compared to $f'(a) = 2a$. Thus for $a_p$ small enough, the discriminant $\Delta$ will be a square.